# Jackson JSON Convert JSON Object into HashMap

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I'm starting using jackson json after Jaunt, but i can't understand some details in deserialization.

I have JSON response from server, here it is:
[image]

```html
{
  success: true,
  stickers: [
     {
      id: "88899",
      name: "",
      img: ""
      },
    {
      id: "13161",
      name: "3DMAX",
      img: ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a Sticker class in my project

```html
public class Sticker {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("img")
    private String imgUrl;

  //getters and setters and constructors
}
```

**I want to read this response and create a List of Stickers:
List(Sticker) stickerList;**

**Another task (if it is possible with jackson tools), i want to create HashMap(String, Sticker) during deserilization instead of List(Sticker) **

**How to do it easy and properly?**

I have found a solution for List: I created class

```html
public class StickerPage {

    @JsonProperty("stickers")
    private List<Sticker> stickerList;

    public List<Sticker> getStickerList() {
        return stickerList;
    }

    public void setStickerList(List<Sticker> stickerList) {
        this.stickerList = stickerList;
    }
}
```

And used it for this:

```html
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        StickerPage stickerPage = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, StickerPage.class);
        HashMap<String, Sticker> stickerHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Sticker sticker : stickerPage.getStickerList()) {
            stickerHashMap.put(sticker.getName(), sticker);
        }
```

But it looks weird i think, can you help me with this task?

Comment: You can create a custom Deserializer.